# Css stylesheet loaded as html in Firefox

Tags: html, css, asp.net, firefox

I've got a css file injected into my asp.net web form application page through a base page. The method I use look like the following:

```
 private void InjectLocalStyleSheet()
    {
        if (this.Page.Header == null)
            return;

        Literal cssFile = new Literal()
        {
            Text =
                @"<link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""" + Page.ResolveUrl("~/Common/Theme.css") + 
                @""" />"
        };
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssFile);
    }
```

When I run the page in firefox, that css file gives me a 302 warning. Apparently, firefox view this file as html type while I've specified the type to be "text/css".
[snap of request and response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHCQh.png)
I also run the web page in Chrome and get "Failed to load resouce: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Anyone has an idea about what is going on? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I ran this locally with firefox and chrome and got no error.  I have firefox 40.0.2

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding permissions to the web.config; I suppose this is because my pages have some kind of limits for anonymous users. But thanx anyway. :)